# Send an HTML email within a shell script under Linux

Tags: linux

I want to be able to send an HTML email under Linux command line. I'm doing the following:

```
echo "<b>HTML Message goes here</b>" | mail -s "$(echo -e "This is the subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" foo@example.com
```

This work for my first server, but not for the second.

The emails are successfully sent, but the HTML format is not recognized if the email was sent from the second server. The HTML tags appear as string in mail body. What can be the reason?

Comment: save both emails and do a diff

Comment: I expect you'll need to set the `content-type` or something and also provide a plaintext version of the text.

Comment: content-type is set as shown in code

Comment: [Sending HTML mail using a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3317174/12892)